# FLTK picture not showing

Tags: c++, fltk

I can't put any pictures to my FLTK project:

```
#include <FL/Fl.h>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.h>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.h>
#include <FL/Fl_Button.H>
#include <FL/FL_JPEG_Image.H>

Fl_Box* mypicturebox;
Fl_JPEG_Image* myimage;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   Fl_Window window(700, 600, "collection");
   Fl_Button *button1=new Fl_Button(0 ,0 ,100, 50, "open");
    button1->labelfont(FL_BOLD + FL_ITALIC);
   Fl_Button button2(270, 400, 120, 50, "previous image");
   Fl_Button button3(400, 400, 120, 50, "next image");
   Fl_Button button4(600, 0, 100, 50, "close");
   Fl_JPEG_Image *myimage = new Fl_JPEG_Image("nicepic.jpg");
   mypicturebox = new Fl_Box(20, 20, 100, 100);
   mypicturebox->image(myimage);
   mypicturebox->redraw();
   window.show();
   return Fl::run();
}
```

Comment: Where is `nicepic.jpg` stored? Is it in the `PATH` or in the same directory as your executable? If not, then sure, it probably won't work indeed. Needs more info please.

Comment: Why, what goes wrong?

Comment: After fixing your `#include` statements your code works fine for me. `#include` statements are case-sensitive on `POSIX` systems.

Comment: @underscore_d its in the same file with my project

Comment: @Galik it doesnt show the picture in the popup window

Comment: @Galik what exactly did you fix in the include statements?

Comment: @Galik it shows the buttons all of them but not the image

Comment: @GiorgosPsilos So it's **not** in the environment `PATH` nor the folder of the executable that gets run, as I asked? or is it? because if it **isn't**, then this is _expected_ not to work, because you need either to specify an absolute path in your code, or put the image file somewhere that the exe can find it.

Comment: @underscore_d i have a folder for the project. in this folder there is the project.sln and the image nicepic.jpg so i figure its in the same directory

Comment: The image needs to be in the same directory you run the program from. Not where the program is kept, but where it is run from.

Comment: You need a window.end() after creating all the bits for window.